# Set a default value to combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox to which I assign values as below:

```
<ComboBox Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ProductName,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"
          SelectedValuePath="ProductID"/>
```

I add a value "ALL" to the collection ProductsList. I have a combobox column in a datagrid which uses the same ProductList, which shouldnt show "ALL". Is there a way to add ALL to the combobox in XAML rather than adding it to the collection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CompositeCollection`, This allows you to combine collections and static items into a single `ItemSource`

Example:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Products" Source="{Binding ProductsList}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem>All</ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Products}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Note: You will have to create a `CollectionViewSource` for your `ProductsList` to use it in the `CollectionContainer` but that's pretty trivial. You mentioned that you are using the `ProductsList` elsewhere so you could define the `CollectionViewSource` in the `Window.Resources` or views Resources instead of in the `ComboBox` resources then you can reuse it.

Comment: This worked. But i want "ALL" to be selected as default. I have a property ProductSelected, which is by default set as "ALL". And i was setting it SelectedItem="{Binding ProductSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
It was working earlier when i was adding ALL to collection, but now it doesnt work.

Comment: you can just set `SelectedIndex-"0"` in the xaml

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ALL" to `ProductsList`, but hide it using [`CollectionView.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter.aspx) where you don't need it.

See [CollectionView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).